# Grounding Frigidaire 27 inch double wall oven (junction box)

Tags: grounding, junction-box, oven

Installing Frigidaire 27 inch double wall oven that has a whip with insulated ground. Ran new 8/3 Romex from breaker box to oven that has bare ground.

Frigidaire instructions say to connect both ground wires to junction box grounding screw. Most things I’ve read online say to use a pigtail for more than one ground wire. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take your NM cable ground and loop it around the junction box grounding screw first and then extend the end outward and wire nut it to your oven ground.